# HTML: Flash Object/Embed not working in IE?

Tags: html, flash, internet-explorer, object, embed

I don't want to use a library to make it more efficient. I've tested this in Chrome and FF and it works, but IE is a nogo (7, 8, and 9):

```
<!--[if IE]>
            <object
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                data="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf"
                codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0"
                pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
                classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
                width="300"
                height="168.75">

                <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" />  
                <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />     
                <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"provider":"pseudostreaming","url":"/uploads/videos/Produce.mp4"},"screen":{"height":"100pct","top":0},"plugins":{"controls":{"timeColor":"#ffffff","borderRadius":"0px","bufferGradient":"none","backgroundColor":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)","timeBorderRadius":20,"progressGradient":"none","height":26,"tooltips":{"marginBottom":5,"buttons":false},"opacity":1,"timeFontSize":12,"bufferColor":"#a3a3a3","border":"0px","buttonColor":"#ffffff","mute":false,"autoHide":{"enabled":true,"hideDelay":500,"mouseOutDelay":500,"hideStyle":"fade","hideDuration":400,"fullscreenOnly":true},"backgroundGradient":"none","width":"100pct","display":"block","sliderBorder":"1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.7)","buttonOverColor":"#ffffff","url":"flowplayer.controls-3.2.5.swf","timeBgColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0, 0)","scrubberBarHeightRatio":0.2,"bottom":0,"buttonOffColor":"rgba(130,130,130,1)","sliderColor":"#000000","zIndex":1,"scrubberHeightRatio":0.6,"tooltipTextColor":"#ffffff","sliderGradient":"none","spacing":{"time":6,"all":2},"timeBgHeightRatio":0.8,"name":"controls","timeSeparator":" ","left":"50pct","tooltipColor":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)","durationColor":"#b8d9ff","timeBorder":"0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)","progressColor":"#4599ff","scrubber":true,"builtIn":false,"margins":[2,12,2,12]},"rtmp":{"netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://vod01.netdna.com/play","url":"http://builds.flowplayer.netdna-cdn.com/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf"}}}' />
            </object>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if !IE]><!-->
            <object id="flowplayer" width="300" height="168.75" wmode="transparent"
                data="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf"  
                classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash">      

                <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" />  
                <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />     
                <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"provider":"pseudostreaming","url":"/uploads/videos/Produce.mp4"},"screen":{"height":"100pct","top":0},"plugins":{"controls":{"timeColor":"#ffffff","borderRadius":"0px","bufferGradient":"none","backgroundColor":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)","timeBorderRadius":20,"progressGradient":"none","height":26,"tooltips":{"marginBottom":5,"buttons":false},"opacity":1,"timeFontSize":12,"bufferColor":"#a3a3a3","border":"0px","buttonColor":"#ffffff","mute":false,"autoHide":{"enabled":true,"hideDelay":500,"mouseOutDelay":500,"hideStyle":"fade","hideDuration":400,"fullscreenOnly":true},"backgroundGradient":"none","width":"100pct","display":"block","sliderBorder":"1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.7)","buttonOverColor":"#ffffff","url":"flowplayer.controls-3.2.5.swf","timeBgColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0, 0)","scrubberBarHeightRatio":0.2,"bottom":0,"buttonOffColor":"rgba(130,130,130,1)","sliderColor":"#000000","zIndex":1,"scrubberHeightRatio":0.6,"tooltipTextColor":"#ffffff","sliderGradient":"none","spacing":{"time":6,"all":2},"timeBgHeightRatio":0.8,"name":"controls","timeSeparator":" ","left":"50pct","tooltipColor":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)","durationColor":"#b8d9ff","timeBorder":"0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)","progressColor":"#4599ff","scrubber":true,"builtIn":false,"margins":[2,12,2,12]},"rtmp":{"netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://vod01.netdna.com/play","url":"http://builds.flowplayer.netdna-cdn.com/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf"}}}' />

                <!-- EMBED tag for Netscape Navigator 2.0+ and Mozilla compatible browsers -->
                <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="168.75" wmode="transparent"
                    src="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf"
                    flashvars='config={"clip":"/uploads/videos/Produce.mp4"}' /> 
            </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"` is needed for Internet Explorer, not the other way around.