# InnerHTML not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm using Javascript to embed a video into a webpage, using innerHTML, when the viewer is either in Australia or New Zealand.
I've got the script to work in all browsers, but for some reason it is not working in any version of IE.

Here is the Javascript code im using:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var countryName = geoip_country_name();
        var boxbaby = document.getElementById('tvc'); 
    var video = "<embed type='application/x-shockwave-flash' src='../htm/summer-tvc/player.swf' id='summertvc' width='452' height='255' flashvars='skin=../htm/summer-tvc/skins/mySkin.swf&thumbnail=../htm/summer-tvc/thumbnail.jpg&video=http://f4player.googlecode.com/files/inhibited-island.mp4' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' bgcolor='#000000' />";


    if (countryName == "Australia" || countryName == "New Zealand") { 
        document.getElementById('tvcontent').innerHTML = video;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('tvcontent').innerHTML = "<img src='../images/pages/summer-tvc/tvc-outside-area.jpg' alt='Due to legal restrictions you are unable to view this video as your IP address is registered outside of Australia and New Zealand. We apologise for the inconvenience.'/>";
    }; 

</script>
```

Here is the HTML

```
   <div id="tvc"> 
  <div id="tvcontent"></div>  
   </div>
```

Any body got any idea why it wouldn't work in IE?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to use the `<object>` tag.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655585/html-flash-object-embed-not-working-in-ie) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a doctype problem.  Try defining a doctype on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

> The `<EMBED>` tag can also be used to add a SWF file to a web page, but it is an older tag and now obsolete.

IE requires [object tag](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html) and not the embed tag.

Comment: The `<embed>` element is valid in HTML5. IE support may not have caught up yet.